# How do we decide if 中 is ちゅう or じゅう?

Tags: words, pronunciation

How do we decide if 中 is ちゅう or じゅう ?

For example, in this sentence １０人中３人はビデオを持っている which pronunciation should we use?

What about this: そのピアニストの演奏中、彼らは一心に耳を傾けた。

Comment: 中 is read as ちゅう in both examples.  I cannot explain why right now.

Comment: @Tsuyoshi thx for the confirmation =P

Answer (score 22, accepted):

- **じゅう** (or, rarely: ぢゅう) is used for expressions covering a **length** of time (resp. area) from start to finish, in its entirety. I.e. "through", "all of":

> 一年中【いちねんじゅう】 all year
>
> 一日中【いちにちじゅう】 all day
>
> 世界中【せかいじゅう】 all over the world

- **ちゅう** is for pointing a particular time (resp. specific location) out of an interval (resp. general area). I.e. "out of", "during":

> 午前中【ごぜんちゅう】 [at some point] during morning
>
> 会議中【かいぎちゅう】 in a meeting [e.g. "he is in a meeting *at the moment*"]

Note that in some cases, both can be used and the only way to tell would be from context (e.g. an expression followed by に is more likely to be ちゅう) or in speech:

> 来月中【らいげつじゅう】 all of next month
>
> 来月中【らいげつちゅう】 [some time] next month

Comment: cool, btw just to confirm, is the 中 in the 2 sentences (in the question) both ちゅう and not じゅう ?

Comment: Hmn, I *would* have said じゅう, since there's an idea of continuity (they listened carefully throughout the whole thing, not just at a specific point in time), but Google seems to think otherwise.

Comment: For some reason, verbal noun is always with ちゅう. The usages are (1) shows state: `会議中 = is in a meeting` (2) as adverb, it means "throughout the course of 〜": `会議中眠っていた = Slept throughout the meeting` (3) used with に, it points a moment. `会議中に… = sometime in the meeting,…`.

Answer (score 2):

"out of" is 「ちゅう」, "through" is 「じゅう」.

> 中 ちゅう
>   (suf,abbr,n-suf) medium; average; middle; moderation; middle school; China; in; out of (e.g. three out of ten people); during (a certain time when one did or is doing something); (P)
>   中 じゅう
>   (suf) through; throughout; in the course of; all over or throughout (e.g. a place)

**EDIT:**

That second example is "during", so 「ちゅう」.

Comment: btw isn't it true that じゅう can also mean "in; out of (e.g. three out of ten people);" ?

Answer (score -1):

１０人中３人はビデオを持っている

Here, 中 reading is うち

Comment: You give a different reading from the other comments/answers. Could you maybe give a bit more detail?