# What is the purpose of 中 in ダウンロード中?

Tags: meaning, suffixes

When I am downloading something, this comes up. I guess it would mean that the download is in progress or something but it seems a little unexpected to have that there. Is it something that you'd say out loud for something else that is progressing or would it be exclusively for digital progressions?

Comment: I would write an answer, but now I'm 食事中, so you have to check the [dictionary](http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%B8%AD).

Comment: If this weren't a translation question without research effort, it would probably be a duplicate of http://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/2790/1628

Comment: omg guys you don't need to be mean, I have of course looked in a dictionary. I just expected that there would be some kind of other element to it and not just attaching it to the end of something. It's mainly a question about the grammatical usage of 中 in this situation and how it could be used in other similar things and I guess I get the idea now thanks to the first comment.

Comment: @Earthliŋ I also found this question: http://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/5369/1478  Maybe either 5369 or 2790 should be closed as a duplicate of the other?

Comment: @user13622 You're right, my tone was out-of-place, especially for a "first post". For this question (or for next time), if you looked in a dictionary or did anything else, please do include what you found in your question. We do get a lot of requests like "what does this mean [Japanese sentence]" from people that haven't looked in a dictionary, even from people that don't speak any Japanese...

Comment: I understand! Thank-you, I'll explain my next question better

Answer (score 8):

The kanji 中 on the end as a kind of suffix generally has two different meanings, depending on context and how it's read.

- **When read as ちゅう:** *"in the middle of doing; in the state of being"*, as in l'électeur's examples.
- **When read as じゅう:** *"all over, throughout; sometime during"*, as in 体{からだ}中{じゅう} *"all over the body, all throughout the body"* or 今日{きょう}中{じゅう} *"sometime during today"*.

Answer (score 5):

「～～[中]{ちゅう}」 = "~~ in progress", "~~ in session", "in the middle of ~~", etc.

"We Are Open!"

[image]

"Under Construction"

[image]